# How to Batch edit a data_bag

Tags: chef-infra, databags

I have a data_bag with 40+ items and need to add certain parameters to most of them.

Is there a way to edit, e.g. with knife, all data_bag items? So far, all I can see is to have each item open in my editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through all of them with cycle and save each into file by calling

```
for item in <item1> <item2> <item3> ; do
  knife data bag show <data_bag> $item -Fj > my_data_bag/$item.json
done
```

Then add the required parameters into every json file by copy/paste or some macro. And update the bag items on chef-server by calling:

```
knife data bag from file <data_bag> my_data_bag/*.json
```

Comment: You probably want to use the `-Fj` option to generate JSON data as the default output format is YAML.

Comment: Thanks, added it to the answer.

Comment: Also, Chef 11 has incorporated knife-essentials so you could do: `knife download data_bags/*` then edit each of the data bag json files and `knife upload data_bags/*`. Reference here: https://github.com/jkeiser/knife-essentials